# Printing exponential values in gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am working with exponential values and would like to use `gtsummary` tables to generate a summary table with the median/IQR. While having exponential values in the data, gtsummary gives the results with decimals. Is there a way to print them with exponential. Here is a quick example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
df <- tibble(x = letters[1:10], 
             y = c(0.00000e+00, 2.16934e-05,
                   0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                   0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
                   4.04793e-05, 0.00000e+00,
                   8.53971e-05, 2.02867e-04))
df %>% select(y) %>% 
  tbl_summary(type = list(everything() ~ "continuous"),
              digits = all_continuous() ~ 20)
```

I increased the number of decimals showing up but it is not what I would prefer. Is there a way to show the results with exponential values?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a scientific notation formatting function in the digits argument. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)

df <- 
  dplyr::tibble(
    x = letters[1:10], 
    y = c(0.00000e+00, 2.16934e-05,
          0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
          0.00000e+00, 0.00000e+00,
          4.04793e-05, 0.00000e+00,
          8.53971e-05, 2.02867e-04)
  )

df %>% 
  select(y) %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    type = list(everything() ~ "continuous"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ function(x) format(x, digits = 6, scientific = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **N = 10** |
| --- | --- |
| y | 0e+00 (0e+00, 3.57828e-05) |

<sup>Created on 2023-05-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>